# Asynchronous initialization in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, initialization

I am currently making an Objective-C library for an API. To easily manage the data, I have created some classes acting as models.

For example, I have an `Account` class which contains all the data concerning one specific account. I would like to make it easy to init this class and I thought about something like this :

```
@interface Account : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger accountID;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *username;

// Other properties...

+ (instancetype)accountWithUsername:(NSString *)username success:(void (^)(Account *))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure;
- (instancetype)initWithUsername:(NSString *)username success:(void (^)(Account *))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure;

@end
```

```
@implementation Account

+ (instancetype)accountWithUsername:(NSString *)username success:(void (^)(Account *))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
{
    return [[JPImgurAccount alloc] initWithUsername:username success:success failure:failure];
}

- (instancetype)initWithUsername:(NSString *)username success:(void (^)(Account *))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
{
    self = [super init];

    // Launch asynchronous requests, the callback will be called when it's finished

    return self; // Returning an empty object until the asynchronous request is finished
}

@end
```

However, returning an empty object through the `init` method bothers me a bit and I ask myself if it's a really good idea but I can't find why it could be risky.

So I'm asking you: can I use this structure? If not, why? Should I go in classic way with a single `init` method coupled to a `loadWithUsername:(NSString *)username success:(void (^)(JPImgurAccount *))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure` method?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your concerns?

Comment: I can't really explain why it bothers me like this. I searched for source codes written in that way and I didn't manage to find some, so I thought that if nobody is doing this it could be because there is a good reason behind...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think your approach is good practice. As a user of the API, when I see a method that starts with "init" I expect the returned object to be ready to use immediately.
It looks like you need to use the Factory design pattern. Create an AccountFactory class with this method:

```
+ (void)createAccountWithUsername:(NSString*)username success:(void (^)(Account *))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure;
```

Notice that it returns void, so the user understand that the object is only available once the request has finished successfully. Also, the user understand that he's not expected to create an instance of Account directly.
That's the approach I would use.

Comment: This seems to be a better solution, but do I really need to create an `AccountFactory` class ? Can't I reuse the `accountWithUsername:success:failure` with `void` as the returned value? Is there an advantage to use a factory?

Comment: @Nesk No, yes, and no, respectively. It's very common to use class methods to create objects in Objective-C, but I can't think of any time when I've seen a separate factory class in Obj-C.

Comment: You don't _have_ to create a factory, but since you're writing an API that other developers will use, you should be as informative as possible. A class called `AccountFactory` leaves no doubt to the developer as to what this class is for. With a class called `Account`, the developer will need to read some comments or to see an example before he understands that he's not supposed to create an `Account` instance.

Comment: The issue with the factory design pattern is that I will have other classes like `Album` or `Image`, if I have to create a factory for each class it will be a bit to much. I have two ideas, tell me what you think about them please. First, create a general factory with methods to initialize various classes, like `createAccountWithUsername:success:failure`, `createAlbumWithID:success:failure`... Or Avoid using factories but create a method like `loadWithUsername:success:failure` to use after `[[Account alloc] init]` thus the developer will know that the object returned by `init` isn't complete.

Comment: Go for the first option. Create a generic factory with one method (or more) for each type of object you need to create. Do not return a "pending" object to the user and hope he understand what to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

> However, returning an empty object through the init method bothers me a bit and I ask myself if it's a really good idea but I can't find why it could be risky.

You're right. It's a bad idea. A lot of people would just use the result right away without understanding its initialization is happening asynchronously. The other problem is that if you return an object, they will assume it is a valid one. So if the account ultimately cannot be initialized, you have clients who probably won't check to see if it initialized correctly. This also makes execution of client's code unnecessarily weird.

The idiom used in Apple's frameworks is typically a **Request**. So there are a few classes which use this design which you can look to for guidance, so that the APIs are more familiar (Their names contain "Request"). Some will use delegation, but blocks are generally preferable -- especially for something as simple as this.

Using this approach, you could make it so that the only way a client could (reasonably) access an instance of an `Account` would be through the `AccountRequest` APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a class method, similar to yours (with two blocks, one for success and one for failure) but omitting a return type. This syntax fits in with normal Objective-C style. For instance, you could have:

```
+ (void)loadAccountWithUsername:(NSString *)username success:(void (^)(Account *))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure
```

Using 'void' over an empty object is greatly preferred, as returning an object that doesn't serve any purpose is redundant and pointless. To reaffirm to the user that the Account class cannot be initialised in the 'traditional' way (via `[[Account alloc] init]`), you could make `init` throw an exception describing the required initialisation flow is through the class method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this structure, but most people use **Key Value Observing** to notify interested classes of changes to properties. You would still issue your asynchronous request during init. But instead of returning the class later in a callback, you just issue notifications of changed properties when the request completes.